# What kind of cocktail would Gin Mare be best suited for?

Tags: gin

Recently, I started paying more attention to the shelf of the "forbidden bottles" in pub's.
I saw lots of time, a gin called Mare (reference [here](http://www.ginfoundry.com/gin/gin-mare-gin/)), which seems to be a very good bottle, with a particular "mediterranean" taste.

Except the classic gin tonic, is there some cocktail who enhance this particular gin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tasted that gin*, but from the description of the botanicals (*"rosemary, thyme, olive, and basil"*) it seems to be crying out for savory rather than sweet. It sounds like a [red snapper](https://www.diffordsguide.com/cocktails/recipe/1665/red-snapper) would be good (essentially a bloody mary with gin instead of vodka). Also sounds like a classic or dirty martini might be nice, depending on the vermouth on hand.

---

*yet... judging by the [rave reviews](https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/p/12329/mare-mediterranean-gin) I will have to try it soon!

Comment: i'll try the martini solution i think...sounds tempting (also i doesn't love bloody mary), glad to let you discover this bottle